# ruby on rails SQLite problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

Am trying out Ruby on Rails in Windows XP using the Hello World example.  Encountered this error ?  Not sure how to fix this

When I downloaded sqllite from the website, copy the dll to windows/system32.

then run "gem install sqlite3-ruby".  It shows up with lots of "No definition for _wrap_sqlite3_*"

then in Firefox, http://localhost:3000/hello/index, this shows up.

Gem::Exception in HelloController#index

can't activate sqlite3-ruby (= 1.2.1, runtime), already activated sqlite3-ruby-1.2.5-x86-mswin32

This error occurred while loading the following files:
   sqlite3/driver/native/driver
   sqlite3_api

Michael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following the steps in this [article](http://www.skorks.com/2009/08/installing-and-using-sqlite-with-ruby-on-windows/), in particular they note that a better location for the sqlite dll is in the ruby bin directory.

Placing it there may also help get sorted what version is loaded.

Failing that, I'd do a gem uninstall sqlite3-ruby and then reinstall it.

Comment: I got the exact same error. Needed to uninstall version 1.2.1 AND get the DLL as well.